# Get value from HashMap using JSTL and variable as an argument

Tags: java, jstl

I have a HashMap and trying to get value from it, using another variable as an argument. Here is the code

```
<c:forEach var="t" items="${userTasks}">
        <tr>
            <td>${t.task}</td>
            <td><${t.deadline}</td>
            <td>${difficultyMap[${t.difficulty}]}</td>
            <td>${t.done}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

difficultyMap - my HashMap, t.difficulty - Integer value. The error is

> PWC6038: "${difficultyMap[${t.difficulty}" contains invalid
>   expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing:
>   ${difficultyMap[${t.difficulty}

${difficultyMap[1]} works ok, but i need to use variable as an argument, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the nested `${}`. Like this:

```
<td>${difficultyMap[t.difficulty]}</td>
```

EL expressions are delimited using a leading dollar sign (`$`) and both leading and trailing braces `{}`.

Since you're working **within** an expression, you don't have to create another EL expression to access some variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, tried different variants, but not the simplest